# jquery effect .shake() firing strangely in different browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My `.shake()` effect is giving me the business across multiple browsers.  For instance, in Chrome, if I hover quickly, I get a queue buildup problem.  If I try implementing `.stop()` before my shake effect, the element will begin its downward shake and then just hang there without the animation completing and with the element completely out of place.
 In IE, the animation fires more than once (even if I haven't hovered quickly in and out).  And annoyingly, if I keep the mouse on the link, it will fire the animation over and over and over.

I've tried playing around with .stop() and different variations of its true/false arguments.  I've also tried using queue:false on each step of the animation.  I even tried putting the .shake effect with times:0 on the mouseleave portion of the function (with hilarious results).  At a loss as to what to try next.

My code is below, but [here is a link to the menu with the shake problem](http://heatherwaltersonline.com/alabamabunkers/services_offered.html).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.shake').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'color': '#fc0'
        }, 150).effect('shake', {
            times: 1,
            distance: 12,
            direction: 'down'
        }, 50);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'color': '#8a600f'
        }, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to add `.stop(true,true)` just before each `.animate()`, but you said you've tried that.

You can test whether the element is currently animated and only queue a new animation if needed:

```
$('.shake').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.is(":animated")) {
       $this.animate({
            'color': '#fc0'
       },150).effect(
            'shake', {
            times:1,
            distance:12,
            direction: 'down'
       }, 50 );
    }
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
       'color': '#8a600f'
    },500); 
});
```

See the [`:animated` selector doco](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) for more info.

Comment: This is much more consistent!  The only drawback and considering how minor it is I'll ignore it is that no other element on the page with that class will fire as long as one is firing, but you have to be very fast with the mouse to notice it as it's such a fast animation.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You should be able to have multiple elements with animations firing, because the code I've shown specifically tests whether the current element is animated - in fact I went back to your page and I see you've added my code and it works for multiple elements. @ahren - your suggestion will break it: `this` doesn't have an `.is()` method. (Note: the only reason I created the `$this` variable was because it is less efficient to repeat `$(this)`.)

Comment: While it works for multiple elements if you mouse quickly over two adjacent links back and forth the animation will not start at all.  Is there a default pause time of a certain number of milliseconds in the .hover() method in JQuery?

Comment: I think it's not starting with the rapid back-and-forth because the animation from the mouse _out_ will still be going on the element over quite a long (500ms) interval. However, I notice that the shake seems to trigger mouse _out_ by moving the element out from under the mouse pointer, so the colour changes back to normal even if you move the mouse in once and leave it there. With that in mind, I'd be inclined to remove the `.animate()` call from the mouse _out_ and instead chain it on the end of the mouse _in_, after the `.effect()`. Or just leave it as it is now, still a nice effect...

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't bother me really as is now, either.  Truth be told, I'm tired of fooling with it, heh heh :)  Thanks for your help!